# What actually happens when Model goes out of using scope?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, scope

I'm implementing db models with using blocks to don't confuse about *disposing* and any related *unmanaged resource requirements* but I want to know (basically) what happens when db model goes out of using block scope. Question isn't about *disposing* or *memory* (I know, it does it automatically for us). Question about *SQL connection* and related instances.

So, here is a simple (`ActionResult`) example:

```
Account account;
using(AccountsModel accountModel = new AccountsModel())
{
    account = accountsModel.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Username == username);
    if(account == null) return;

    account.Name = name;
    accountsModel.SaveChanges();
}

ViewBag.Name = account.Name; // Is it safe?
return View();
```

The question is: "Is it safe to access `Account` class instance (that provided by `AccountsModel`) out of model's using scope?"

**Note:** I know, I couldn't/can't perform any update on the table out of scope.

Comment: Dispose method gets invoked. what ever is in it happens

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary "Question isn't about disposing or memory, it's about SQL connection and related instances"

Comment: if you override Dispose method and put nothing in it then nothing happens. `using` will call Dispose. thats all. you can do math in Dispose. play a game. anything!

Comment: I'm not overriding/overloading `Dispose` method, this is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `AccountsModel`'s `dispose` call does not do anything to destroy it, then there should be no problem continuing to access an object created by the model.

So, it really depends more on the implementation of `dispose`

Comment: I'm not overriding/overloading `Dispose` method, so is it safe?

Comment: If you don't I'd imagine that all that's done is any connections are cleaned up. Anything created in memory should be fine. Is this an entity framework model?

Comment: Yes, `AccountsModel` is an `ADO.Net Entity Model`.